# Measure elapsed time between two MotionEvents in Android

Tags: java, android, time, elapsed

I'm new in Android programming so I am asking for your help in my problem.
I am trying to measure in seconds/milliseconds the amount of time between a MouseEvent.ACTION_DOWN and MouseEvent.ACTION_UP.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    long start=0;
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        // manage down press
        start=System.nanoTime();//START
        System.out.println("START");
    }
    else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        // manage move
        System.out.println(event.getRawX()+","+event.getRawY());
    }
    else {
        // manage up
        long finish=System.nanoTime()//FINISH
        long seconds = (finish-start) / 1000000000;//for seconds
        Toast.makeText(this, "FINISH, duration: "+seconds, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        System.out.println("FINISH, duration: "+seconds);
    }
    return true;
}




Logcat:
03-19 04:04:27.140: I/System.out(4348): START
03-19 04:04:27.160: I/System.out(4348): 517.0,280.0
03-19 04:04:27.190: I/System.out(4348): 517.0,280.0
03-19 04:04:27.200: I/System.out(4348): 517.0,280.0
03-19 04:04:27.220: I/System.out(4348): 517.0,280.0
03-19 04:04:27.250: I/System.out(4348): 517.0,280.0
03-19 04:04:27.260: I/System.out(4348): 517.0,280.0
03-19 04:04:27.300: I/System.out(4348): 517.0,280.0
03-19 04:04:27.310: I/System.out(4348): 517.0,280.0
03-19 04:04:27.330: I/System.out(4348): FINISH, duration: 16545
```

> My problem consist in fact that seconds variable doesn't show what I
>   want, I even don't know if its measuring correctly.For the above
>   example duration was 16545 (???!?!?) but it should have been between
>   1-3 seconds.What shall I do to measure correctly in seconds or
>   milliseconds the time between two MotionEvents or what am I wrong in
>   my example ? Thank you !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
long startTime;
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) 
        startTime = System.nanoTime();    

    else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        long elapseTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
        //do whatever u want with elapseTime now, its in nanoseconds
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, looking at your code I discovered my fault: variable long start should be declared global, not local in my function, thank you very much !

Comment: You should use `System.nanoTime()` instead of `System.currentTimeMillis()`. Please read javadoc for both functions, it is said that `currentTimeMillis()` should not be used for measuring intervals because it might be adjusted at runtime.

Comment: Thanks keaukraine, accomodated changes to use nanoTime()

Comment: There is a problem with this answer - it will just tag the time that the event is processed, not when it is generated - thus it depends on things like thread contention and can be way off.  CvR's answer shows the right way to get the timestamp - use `MotionEvent.getEventTime()` instead (this internally uses System.nanoTime()), but does it when the event is generated.

Answer (score 13):

A `MotionEvent` has a timestamp. Use `getEventTime()` to access it.

In fact, since there is no guarantee that the `MotionEvent` is delivered immediately to your code, this timestamp is more accurate than any times you get from `System.getCurrentTimeMillis()`.

Comment: +1 This, used with `android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis()` is actually the correct solution to finding the time between down and up events.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution described by @CvR:

```
private long startTimeInMilliSec;
@Override 
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) 
        startTimeInMilliSec = event.getEventTime();    

    else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        long elapsedTime = event.getEventTime() - startTimeInMilliSec;
        //do whatever u want with elapsedTime now, its in milliseconds 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Each event also have `getDownTime()` method. So when you received `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` you can simple use

`event.getDownTime() - event.getEventTime()`

to calculate elapsed time.