# How can I detect time press duration of button in android?

Tags: android, button, onpress

I want to detect time press duration of button by using `setOnTouchListener` with `onTouch` method

How I can do this ?

Comment: Maybe answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22606977/how-can-i-get-button-pressed-time-when-i-holding-button-on

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Measure elapsed time between two MotionEvents in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9764310/measure-elapsed-time-between-two-motionevents-in-android)

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using `onTouchListener`

```
long FirstTouchTime ;
long duration ; 

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) 
        FirstTouchTime = System.currentTimeMillis();    

    else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        duration = System.currentTimeMillis(); - FirstTouchTime ;
        //duration value in millisecond 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this :

```
long mLastClickTime;

findViewById(R.id.button).setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
      @Override
      public void onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
         if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) 
            mLastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();

         else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            long duration = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mLastClickTime;
            // using threshold of 1000 ms
            if (duration > 1000) {
               // do your magic here
            }
         }
      }    
});
```